# I need a help to make sound for the notification

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made a script using PHP to send my phone a notification using firebase cloud messaging everything is ok but I need to include with the notification a sound

```
   <?php

    function sendoo($to='',
    $data = array()){
    $apiKey = 'hide';
    $fields = array ('to' => $to, 'notification' => $data);   
    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' .$apiKey,'Content-Type: 
    application/json');
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);

    }
    $to = "hide";
    $data = array(
    'body' => 'new order'
     );
     print_r(sendoo($to, $data));
     ?>
```

Comment: php runs on the server - you need javascript to play sounds in the client ( browser )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification in $fields

```
$fields = array(
    'to' => 'something',
    'sound' => 'default',
    'body' => 'hello',
    'title' => 'Message',
    '_displayInForeground'=> 'true',
    'channelId'=>'default',
);
```

channelId is important to fire the sound!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want custom sound or default sound?

First put this line of code

```
 Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

Then in order to play default sound put this:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

If you want  in order to play custom sound save an mp3 file and access it like that:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/notification.mp3");
```

After that use the notifaction manger to send the notification. Note: only use one of these methods if you use both the application will use the default sound. :)

Comment: where should I put this code in my application or in the PHP script?